Correct way to wait for Deno 2 LSP server responses over stdin/stdout pipes
I'm trying to create an lsp tool (client - code editor) that leverages Deno 2's deno lsp subcommand to launch and interact with an lsp server over stdio.
To test this I'm using Deno itself although I want to do this from another language eventually.
I'm getting stuck at the first await writer.close() line; if I wait for the pipe to close then I get the response back from Deno lsp for the initialize command. However then I can't send a follow up message. If I comment out the line then my programme hangs and never gets the response from the lsp printed.
if (import.meta.main) {
  const lsp = new Deno.Command(String.raw`C:\Users\Greedo\.deno\bin\deno.exe`, {
    args: ["lsp"],
    stdin: "piped",
    stdout: "piped",
  }).spawn();

  const json =
    `{"jsonrpc": "2.0","id": "lemon","method": "initialize","params": {"processId": null,"capabilities": {}}}
    `;
  const content_length = json.length;
  const jsonrpc = `Content-Length: ${content_length}

${json}`;

  console.log(jsonrpc);
  const writer = lsp.stdin.getWriter();
  await writer.write(new TextEncoder().encode(jsonrpc));
  await writer.ready;
  await writer.close() //This line I comment out and the process hangs, leave in and the pipe is closed preventing the second message

  const result = await lsp.output();
  console.log("got => ", new TextDecoder().decode(result.stdout));

  writer = lsp.stdin.getWriter();
  await writer.write(new TextEncoder().encode("foo"));
  await writer.ready;
  await writer.close();

  result = await lsp.output();
  console.log("got => ", new TextDecoder().decode(result.stdout));

  lsp.unref();
}

What am I doing wrong? Is there a simpler way to interact synchronously as well?

Deno.ChildProcess#output() returns a promise that "Waits for the child to exit completely, returning all its output and status." You'll need to pipe the streams through streaming message decoders/encoders that conform to the LSP specification.
